# Two cloned git repositories to be used with one Jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, clone

My jenkins job has to grab a python script from one repo, and use it againsts the other repo via bash script, what is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the best way, but this works for me:

Configure Jenkins pipeline to pull Jenkinsfile and sources from main repo.

In Jenkinsfile, pull additional repos as needed:

```
dir('{{ repo2 }}') {
    git url: 'ssh://git@{{ githost }}/{{ project }}/{{ repo2 }}.git',
        credentialsId: {{ credId }}
    sh 'source venv/bin/activate && pip install .'
}
```

(Of course, replacing the above {{ tokens }} as needed.)

Ideally, I would rather setup pre-requisite jobs to build and upload each auxiliary repo to a PyPI repository and let these requirements be satisfied 'normally' in the main repo. (Exercise left for the reader.)